# how to resolve state.set is not a function error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js, reducers

here is code in which i am using immutable.js in reducer. but every time it gives error state.set is not a function.but when i change it with other way (without immutable) it changes

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash-node';
import {Map } from 'immutable'
import {ModuleEvents} from './Actions';
const InitialState =  Map({
currentAdmin: null,
data: {},
User:null
});
export const Reducer = (state = InitialState, action) => {
const {
type,
payload
} = action;
switch (type) {
case ModuleEvents.DATA_AVAILABLE:
{
  state = {
    data: payload,
    loading: false,
    User:null
  };
  return state.set('data',payload).set('loading',true)
}
```

Comment: isnt it this.setState?

Comment: You are overriding the state at `state = { ... };` so it is normal Javascript after that line, not an ImutableJS Map, and you can not use `set`.

Comment: @Tr1et for help me out ))

Answer (score 1):

```
state = {
    data: payload,
    loading: false,
    User:null
  };
```

now state is no more an immutable.js object hence it throws such an error.
Try,

```
   case Modulevents.DATA_AVAILABLE: {
      const entry = {}; // INTERNALLY NOT USING IMMUTABLE.JS
      entry['data'] = item;
      entry['loading'] = false;
      entry['User'] = null;
      return state.merge(entry);
    }
```

Comment: but i want to return immutable state via immutable.js